# Unreal 4.27 became slow at compiling out of nowhere?

Tags: c++, compilation, unreal-engine4

long story short, I've seen a lot of peoples complaining about unreal being slow at compiling but never had this issue before thinking that my laptop's specs are good enough:
RTX 2060 / i5 9th / 512 SSD 16 RAM

But the last few days things were different, Okay I get that modifying the header files might cause some slow compiling but the longest i've ever seen is around 120 seconds in my console,
but now have a look at my latest log output, just a C++ files that trigger a very simple action

> Display: HotReload took 928.2s.

16 Minutes just to compile a small change ? but that's ridiculous.

I'm using Unreal engine 4.27 and Visual studio 2022

and Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does it take 16 minutes if you recompile directly after you've compiled (without changing anything in between)?

Comment: @TedLyngmo Not exactly 16 minutes, i tried it and it took around 7 8 minutes  it always takes above 10 minutes when i change and around half without changing anything, now i started to think something is really off any help ?? EDIT: Its kinda weird happening in every freshly new project, the creation of a new cpp files too takes eternity

Comment: Hmm, that's a tough one. If you compile twice with no changes in between, it should be very fast. It could be something with the build system. If some process is poking around, changing the timestamps of the files, that could affect `make`-based build systems.

Comment: hi @TedLyngmo Its kinda sad that i don't really know what is going on here, I'm not that expert in unreal neither, anyways I've been following some tips and tuts around and I somehow ended up with the last build is fast but the first is slow but not as it was, now changes takes around 7 minutes which is ridiculous of course but when i press compile right away it takes barely 2 seconds, what am i supposed to do here now ?

Comment: That's very hard to say. If it took 7 minutes after you've changed some core stuff that requires rebuilding a lot of libraries, it wouldn't be too bad but I'd expect that changing normal application code wouldn't require more than a few seconds to compile. Perhaps you can start analyzing by first compiling, then making a small change in a file and then when recompiling, look at all the files it recompiles. Are all those really supposed to be depending on the file in which you made a change? If not, something in dependency chain is broken.

Comment: say something is really broken any idea how to repair everything and bring it back to work normally ?

Comment: I'd really try to analyze _why_ a change in a file that shouldn't require a big rebuild still triggers such a rebuild, but if everything else fails, try a clean install on a separate computer and recreate the project there. Not by copying the project from your original because if you've messed up some setting, that would be copied too. Only copy the source files. Eh... that sounds like something that could take time and without actually finding the cause, nothing says it'll work or that you won't end up in the same situation again :-/ Hmm, perhaps not worth it.